# Does A "Connections" Blog/Podcast exist for Math?

Tags: mathematics-education

What I mean is this:

Does there exist a mathematics podcast where a mathematician of some sort looks at undergraduate/graduate mathematical topics and look into the history (how those objects came along) or how mathematical ideas come from places that you never would have guessed (or at least, the average mathematician would not have guessed).

Also if there's one that goes over the intuition/how the problems came about in general?

I'm thinking about starting one, but I want to see what else is done so I can develop something unique (just to give motivation for why I'm asking).

Comment: I was looking at the podcasts mentioned in another podcast-related post, and they all seem to suffer from being very very small and there wouldn't be enough time to really mull over the topic at hand and seriously investigate what brought about these ideas.

Answer (score 6):

John Baez's This Week's Finds are more on the graduate level, and often not so much about the history. But when he *does* give the history it is always nicely written and well researched. http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/twfcontents.html

And yes, John Baez is the grand-daddy of math blogging. He was blogging before blog was even a word...

Answer (score 1):

[Marcus du Sautoy: Symmetry, reality's riddle](http://video.ted.com/talks/podcast/MarcusduSautoy_2009G_480.mp4) I think this really fits some points of your question.