# Why do we use $\varepsilon$ and $\delta$?

Tags: soft-question, ho.history-overview

My understanding (from a talk by Rob Bradley) is that Cauchy is responsible for
the now-standard $\varepsilon{-}\delta$ formulation of calculus, introduced in his
1821 *Cours d’analyse*.  Although perhaps instead it was introduced by Bolzano a few years
earlier.  My question is not about who was first with this notation, but
rather:

> Why were the symbols $\varepsilon$ and $\delta$ used?

Why not, say, $\alpha$ and $\beta$?
(Imagine how different our mathematical discourse would be...)
Are there appropriate (French) words beginning with '*e*' and/or '*d*' that determined the choice?
Or perhaps Cauchy used up $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ for other purposes prior to introducing $\delta,\varepsilon$?  Does anyone know?

Comment: If I had to take a wild guess, I'd say $\delta$ for distance, but I don't have any supporting evidence.

Comment: I heard $\epsilon$ for error, but also have no evidence.

Comment: @Gerald: quote from J.V. Grabiner's Who Gave You the Epsilon? Cauchy and the Origins of Rigorous Calculus (http://www.maa.org/pubs/Calc_articles/ma002.pdf )"The epsilon corresponds to the initial letter in the word “erreur’’ (or “error’’), and Cauchy in fact used for “error’’ in some of his work on probability [31]."

Comment: Presumably there is a reason for our using ε and δ, Igor!

Comment: @Mariano: You are saying that this has a provable answer? That's absurd. My own guess is that $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ were used since the greeks for various angles of the triangle, so $\epsilon, \delta were the first letters with no reserved use, but I do not expect to be able to prove this.

Comment: In France, most of the time (in my undergraduate studies at least) we use $\varepsilon$ and $\eta$ instead of $\varepsilon$ and $\delta$. So I would be surprised if you found a reason for $\delta$. Is this $\delta$ really in Cauchy's work?  

Comment: @Jérôme: apparently, yes: http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k90196z/f47.image (Démonstration).

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer your question -- but I like to tell my calculus students that an "enemy" has challenged their claim of a limit, and they need to be able to "defend" their claim against any challenge.

Comment: @Igor: The accepted answer below comes about as close to being a provable answer as one is going to get for historical questions.  I don't think community wiki automatically applies to a question just because it's a historical or terminological question rather than a mathematical one.  It's true that some questions, such as your hypothetical one, might be almost surely unanswerable, but then my reaction would be to close the question rather than to make it community wiki.

Comment: I remember vaguely a story about an MIT TA who decided to switch the standard role of epsilon and delta and also of 'n' and 'N' 

Comment: @FrankThorne That's really good, as it fits into a narrative of "games", as discussed for example at https://mathoverflow.net/a/88553 and at https://mathoverflow.net/a/38882

Comment: Traditionally, $\ \alpha\ \beta\ \gamma\ \phi\ \psi\ $ stand for angles. Now, not much is left, first of all $\ \delta\ $ and $\ \epsilon\ $ are left.

Comment: To confuse Israeli students: $\delta$ looks like a script Lamed, which would correspond to $\lambda$, which looks like a Gimel (unlike $\gimel$ which looks not very much like one), which in turn corresponds to $\gamma$, which looks like a script A'yin. So all in all, very confusing.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Thanks to H. M. Šiljak for finding the 1983 *Amer. Math. Monthly*
paper by Judith Grabiner, which I feel settles the question (at least for $\epsilon$).
Here is a longer quote encompassing that which H.M. excerpted:

> Mathematicians are used to taking the rigorous foundations of the calculus as a 
>   completed whole. What I have tried to do as a historian is to reveal what went into 
>   making up that great achievement. This needs to be done, because completed wholes by 
>   their nature do not reveal the separate strands that go into weaving them—especially 
>   when the strands have been considerably transformed. In Cauchy's work, though, one 
>   trace indeed was left of the origin of rigorous calculus in approximations—the letter 
>   epsilon. The $\epsilon$ corresponds to the initial letter in the word "erreur" (or "error"), and 
>   Cauchy in fact used $\epsilon$ for "error" in some of his work on probability [31]. It is both 
>   amusing and historically appropriate that the "$\epsilon$," once used to designate the "error" in 
>   approximations, has become transformed into the characteristic symbol of precision 
>   and rigor in the calculus. As Cauchy transformed the algebra of inequalities from a tool 
>   of approximation to a tool of rigor, so he transformed the calculus from a powerful 
>   method of generating results to the rigorous subject we know today.
>
> [31] Cauchy, Sur la plus grande erreur à craindre dans un résultat moyen, et sur le 
>   système de facteurs qui rend cette plus grande erreur un minimum, *Comptes rendus* 
>   37, 1853; in *Oeuvres*, series 1, vol. 12, pp. 114–124.

---

A further finding by H. M. Šiljak (linked in a comment above), 
verifying that Cauchy did indeed use both $\epsilon$ and $\delta$:

         [image: Cauchy title]

      [image]

Comment: So it's $\epsilon$ for error in the answer, and presumably $\delta$ is in reference to *difference* in the input variables. 

Comment: Or possibly that $\delta$ is just the next letter over...

Comment: @Simon: And given the choice between $\delta$ and $\zeta$, the two adjacent letters, it somehow seems natural to choose $\delta$.

Comment: If we have $f(x) = y$, then $&\epsilon$ is a difference in $y$-values and $\delta$ is a difference in $x$-values. $\delta$ comes before $\epsilon$ alphabetically, as $x$ does before $y$.