# History question - why h in the definition of derivative?

Tags: ho.history-overview

Does anyone have a clue where the "h" came from?

Comment: As you can see from the Cauchy clip at the MO question, "Why do we use $\epsilon$ and $\delta$?" (http://mathoverflow.net/questions/82302/), the $h$ was not universal in 1850: Cauchy uses $i$ instead.

Comment: And $h$ immediately precedes $i$ in the alphabet!

Comment: A conjecture. The letter *h* (especially at the beginning of a word) has just the small effect of aspiration. In Latin, it is even mute, like e.g. in the English word *honour*, of Latin origin). So, *h* seems a natural choice for denoting a quantity that is small or tends to $0.$ 

Comment: a, b, c are boring; d is for derivative, e is already taken, f and g are functions, so that leaves h as the first usable letter ;-)

Comment: @Pietro: H was not mute in Latin, it is only mute in modern Italian pronunciation of Latin. See e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin#Phonology and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_spelling_and_pronunciation .

Comment: Curiouser and curiouser - one assumes that Cauchy's use of i didn't catch on for the obvious reason.  Perhaps Mariano is right, and h is just luck of the draw, someone not long after Cauchy didn't want to use i and chose h as the letter preceding it (so I guess we could just as easily have ended up with j).  Maybe it was first used in a popular calculus "textbook" from the late 19th Century.

Thanks for the interesting responses - Suvrit, your explanation reminds me of why 17 is the first really interesting number :-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I  think that use of $h$ in the definition of derivative is linked to the relationship between Calculus of Finite Difference and Differential Calculus.

In the book *Leçons sur le Calcul des Fonctions*, Councier, **1806**, [Lagrange](http://archive.org/stream/leonssurlecalcu01lagrgoog#page/n12/mode/2up):

1. Assigns to Maclaurin and d'Alembert the origin of  differentiation as the limit of finite  differences, (pp. 1);
2. Writes "Considerons un fonction $fx$ d'une variable quelconque $x$. Si la place de $x$ on substitue $x + i$, $i$ étant une quantité quelconque indetermineé, elle divendra $f(x + i)$ ...", (pp. 8);
3. Develops $f(x + i)$ in series: 
   $$f(x+ i) = fx + i f'x + \frac{i^2}{2} f''x + \frac{i^3}{2 . 3}f'''x + \frac{i^4}{2.3.4}f^{iv}+ \mbox{etc}$$ as we can see at (pp. 15), and
4. Writes "Nous appelerons la fonction $fx$ fonction primitive... Nous nommerous de plus la fontion dérivée $f'x$, primière fonction dérivée ou fonction derivée du primier ordre...", (pp. 15).

Notes B of [Lacroix's](http://archive.org/stream/anelementarytre00babbgoog#page/n609/mode/2up) book *An Elementary Treatise on the Differential and Integral Calculus*, Cambridge, **1816**, pp. 599, , using $h$ instead $i$, is based on Lagrange's work.

In **1829**, Dr. Martin Ohm, in *Versuch eines vollkommen consequenten Systems der Mathematik*, Vol. III, pp.53,  Berlin, available [here](http://books.google.com/books/about/Versuch_eines_vollkommen_consequenten_sy.html?id=eQI4AAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y), uses $h$. He writes:

$$f(x+h)=f(x) + \partial f(x).h+\partial^2 f(x) .\frac{h^2}{2!} + \partial^3 f(x) .\frac{h^3}{3!} +.\ldots$$

Also, as we can see, Dr. Martin Ohm uses factorials!! (Martin and Georg Ohm were brothers. Georg discovered the Ohm's Law).

In G. Boole, *Treatise on the Calculus of Finite Differences*, MacMillan, London, **1880**, pp.1, we can read: " The Calculus of Finite Differences may be strictly defined as the science which is occupied about the ratios of the simultaneous increments of quantities mutually dependent. The Differential Calculus is occupied about the limits to which such ratios approach as the increments are definitely diminished" [Boole1](http:////archive.org/stream/treatiseoncalcul00booluoft#page/n15/mode/2up).

At pages 2 and 3 , we can see the definition of derivative using $h$. All arguments are based on Finite Differences [Boole2](http:////archive.org/stream/treatiseoncalcul00booluoft#page/2/mode/2up).

The differentiation was developed based on trigonometric assumptions (method of tangents). A very good history can be found in H.Sloman, *The Claim of Leibnitz to the Invention of the Differential Calculus*, MacMillan, **1860** [Sloman1](http://archive.org/details/claimleibnitzto00slomgoog).

A possible explanation for the use of h in the definition of derivative (**and the link between Differential Calculus and Calculus of Finite Differences**) can be found in this book at page 127, second paragraph [Sloman2](http://archive.org/stream/claimleibnitzto00slomgoog#page/n139/mode/2up).

PS: Although $h$ has been used in the books mentioned above (1816, 1829, 1860 and 1880), Milne-Thomson, in his *recent* book (**1933**), uses $\omega$ instead [Milne-Thomson](http://archive.org/stream/calculusoffinite032017mbp#page/n25/mode/2up).

Milne-Thomson's book  can be considered an example of Euler's notation use.
In *Institutiones calculi differentialis cum eius usu in analysi finitorum ac doctrina serierum*, Chapter 1, *De differentiis finitis*, pp.1, **1787**,  [Euler](http://eulerarchive.maa.org/pages/E212.html) writes "variabilis x capiat incrementum $\omega$" !

Comment: It would seem reasonable to speculate that i stands for increment. It may have been changed to h later to avoid conflicts of notation.

Comment: @Michael I think you are correct. Please, see ref. of Lacroix's book, first paragraph, pp. 599: "... corresponding to the increment h ...".

Comment: Laplace writes: "Nous désignerons ordinairements les variables des fonctions par les dernières letters de l'alphabet, x, y, etc., et las constantes par les premières a, b, c, etc..."

Comment: Interesting, and thanks so much.  One thing I would love to see is the original reference of Taylor which Sloman refers to...

Comment: @Jeff:  Taylor's work about increments is available at 17centurymaths.com/contents/taylorscontents.html. Also, there is a work from L. Feigenbaum, (tufts.edu/as/math/feigenbaum.html) published by Springer (springerlink.com/content/h720142152632171) but I have no access to it.

Comment: The places where Boyle is mentioned in the answer, is it supposed to by Boole?

Comment: For this very old question, we were taught (in UK) in our introductory calculus class on differentiation from first principles (of a single-variable function, x).

$\Delta x$ represents any change in the value of the variable x.

$\delta x$ represents any "small" change in the value of the variable x that is decreased in size and approaches zero "in the limit" (cue hand-waving here).

Comment: $h$ serves the same purpose as $\delta x$. But further, $h$ represents the *height* of the trapezium that "stands on" the x-axis "above" h. The sum of the area of the trapezia (between limits) approximates the area between the upper and lower limits of the integral and "in the limit" (hand-waving) is the value of the area / definite integral.

I have no historic reference to back this up, and this explanation as to why $h$ was used may be "after-the-fact" to justify the use of $h$ - but I like it - and now I have shared with you.