# Mathematical objects whose name is a single letter

Tags: soft-question, big-list, notation

(Not research-level, but perhaps not easily answered elsewhere — you decide if MO can afford the innocent fun. If so, it should likely be “community-wiki” i.e. **one object per answer**.)

> I am seeking stories of mathematical objects that, in context, eat out namespace because their (most usual) name literally is a letter (e.g., in calculus, $e$).

Per discussion in the comments, please rather *exclude* letters that are frozen out by being merely common notation ($e$ in group theory, $g$ in Riemannian geometry, whole alphabets in semisimple Lie theory), and not really the name of any single object. But include: how such (poor?) practice came about; what did or didn’t help reclaim letters (new names, new typography,...); or any good story.

Wikipedia’s [disambiguation pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_(disambiguation)#Science_and_mathematics) can suggest many ($c$, $e$, $i$, $j$, $k$, $o$, $q$, $t$, $F$, $G$, $J$, $K$, $L$, $O$, $P$, $W$, $Y$, $\mathcal O$, $\wp$, $\delta$, $\zeta$, $\eta$, $\vartheta$, $\varkappa$, $\lambda$, $\xi$, $\pi$, $\sigma$, $\tau$, $\chi$, $\mathrm B$, $\Gamma$, $\mathrm H$, $\Xi$, $\Omega$,...), but I am sure that is not all.

Comment: $i$ or $j$ for $\sqrt{-1} $?

Comment: Σ, Π, and of course π (though none of them is fully frozen, e.g. Σ also = Σphere and  π =  πermutation or  πrojection)

Comment: Ш  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tate%E2%80%93Shafarevich_group)
-- but I've seen that used also for the "row of deltas" that is its own Fourier transform by Poisson summation.

Comment: $\aleph$ is owned by set theory, and if you allow font based answers then Lie theory owns the celtic fonts - $\mathfrak{g}$, $\mathfrak{h}$, etc.

Comment: $\emptyset$ - the 28th letter of the alphabet

Comment: The cardinal characteristics of the continuum take care of all the letters.

Comment: I don't quite follow the intent about a letter being frozen out vs. just being a common notation: a paper in number theory might use $\Sigma$ for a set of primes while also using it for summation, or $\pi$ for $3.1415\ldots$ and for an irreducible representation. Context or a few extra words serve to make it clear what means what and neither $\pi$ nor $\Sigma$ is frozen.

Comment: Most of these comments should be answers.

Comment: @KConrad Good point. So let me try to restrict the question to objects whose very name is a letter, and exclude other “frozen letter” phenomena. Of the comments so far, I guess this would fit $i$, $j$, $\pi$, $\aleph$, Tate-Shafarevich Ш, but exclude $\Sigma$, $\Pi$, $\varnothing$, Dirac Ш as normally called another name (*sum*, *product*, *empty set*, *comb*).

Comment: $\mathbb R$?      $\phantom 0$

Comment: Continuing one of Noam's comments, if font matters, then $\mathbb Z$, $\mathbb Q$, $\mathbb R$, and $\mathbb C$. Also probably $\mathbb N$, although there may be some controversy as to exactly what set it represents.

Comment: Will you provide an example of a satisfying story, to ensure that the big list is on topic?

Comment: @MattF.: See the (somewhat complex) story for $\mathfrak{c}$.

Comment: The $\delta$ function? Supposedly Dirac chose the letter based on Kronecker's symbol $\delta_{ij}$

Comment: Does $\wp$ qualify?

Comment: $\Delta$ for the simplicial indexing category

Comment: I very much like Bruce Sagan's reconciliation of combinatorics and real analysis: $\pi = 3142$.

Answer (score 20):

A lovely story of $\nabla$ can be found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nabla_symbol#History)

[image]

Introduced by Hamilton in 1837, his initial notation was ◁. Quotes from Wikipedia:

> The name comes, by reason of the symbol's shape, from the Hellenistic Greek word νάβλα for a Phoenician harp, and was suggested by the encyclopedist William Robertson Smith to Peter Guthrie Tait in correspondence.

(...)

> After receiving Smith's suggestion, Tait and James Clerk Maxwell referred to the operator as nabla in their extensive private correspondence; most of these references are of a humorous character. C. G. Knott's *Life and Scientific Work of Peter Guthrie Tait*:
>
> > It was probably this reluctance on the part of Maxwell to use the term Nabla in serious writings which prevented Tait from introducing the word earlier than he did. The one published use of the word by Maxwell is in the title to his humorous Tyndallic Ode, which is dedicated to the "Chief Musician upon Nabla," that is, Tait.

Comment: Wonderful point, thanks for sharing this!

Answer (score 17):

Amir Alexander's 2014 book *Infinitesimal* says that John Wallis introduced the symbol $\infty$ for infinity (p.280). I asked on HSM,
"[Where did John Wallis get the idea for $\infty$?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/3814/606),"
and user Conifold said that the source might be
"the Egyptian ouroboros symbol, snake biting its tail":

---

[image]

          

<sup>(Image from [mythologian.net](http://mythologian.net/ouroboros-symbol-of-infinity/).)</sup>

---

Comment: $\infty$ is not a letter, so this is not an answer to the question.

Comment: Correct, not a letter. Another theory is that $\infty$ arose as a calligraphed Greek $\omega$...

Answer (score 5):

To get the ball rolling with actual answers...

$\mathfrak{c}$ is the [Cardinality of the continuum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_of_the_continuum).

Comment: The question asks for stories, e.g. how the name came about, and what did or didn’t help reclaim letters.  So far this provides a letter and a link, but not a story.

Comment: @MattF., good point! Unfortunately, I don't know the history of this notation well enough to comment intelligently about it. But this is community wiki, so if anyone else can, please feel free!

Comment: See "[Why did Cantor (and others) use $\mathfrak{c}$ for the continuum?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/2418/606)." The scholarly answers show that Cantor never used "c" for the continuum.

Answer (score 5):

How about the plethora of symmetric functions and generalizations?
[image: polynomials]

This is just a small overview of the various generalizations of Schur polynomials, and related bases of symmetric (or quasi-symmetric) functions.
Furthermore, the notation is not completely standardized.

It does not exactly answer OP's question, but some of these at least are standardized (say the $e_\lambda$, $m_\lambda$).
I myself wonder a bit of the practice in this area.

Answer (score 5):

Imagine how different would be our mathematical discourse if students struggled
with $\alpha$-$\beta$ proofs rather than $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proofs!

From an earlier MO question: "[Why do we use $\epsilon$ and $\delta$?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/82302/6094),"
an answer quoting Judith Grabiner:

> $\epsilon$ corresponds to the initial letter in the word "erreur" (or "error"), and Cauchy in fact used $\epsilon$ for "error" in some of his work on probability."

As @RyanBudney summarizes,
"So it's  $\epsilon$ for error in the answer, and presumably $\delta$ is in reference to difference in the input variables."
Or, as @SimonRose says, "Or possibly that $\delta$ is just the next letter over..."

Comment: Despite Cauchy's sometimes using $\epsilon$ for error, I believe we also owe to him the use of $h$ (as in $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}h$).  I always explain this to my students by some variant of the jocularity "we need a letter to stand for 'a little bit', so we choose $h$ since it doesn't occur anywhere in the phrase."

Answer (score 4):

In set theory, $V$ is universally known as the universe of all sets.

Similarly, meanwhile, $L$ is the [constructible universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_universe).

Comment: What are the stories behind these choices? I've always thought that V was chosen to suggestively depict the cumulative hierarchy, with an empty set at the bottom and spreading out by taking a power set of what one had previously at a successor ordinal (and collecting all previous stages at limit ordinals). But I can't guess where L comes from.

Comment: @ToddTrimble I thought that the $V$ was from 'von Neumann'.

Comment: I also used to think that $V$ stood for von Neumann, but when I looked into it a few years, I recall finding that the usage pre-dated him. Unfortunately, I don't recall now whether I had found it in Frege or Zermelo or where. I vaguely recall it having come up here on MO previously.

Comment: $V$ (or V) was introduced by Peano in his "Arithmetices principia. Nova methodo exposita" from 1889. He uses V for *verum* and $\Lambda$ for *falsum*, and the symbols were adopted to denote the universe of all sets, and the empty set, accordingly (Peano also uses V explicitly for "the class of all individuals"). See pp. viii and xi [here](https://archive.org/details/arithmeticespri00peangoog).

Comment: To $V$ and $L$ one should add $K$, the core model.

Comment: In his 1939 "Consistency proof for the generalized continuum hypothesis", Gödel uses $M$ to denote the constructible universe. He switches to $L$ in his 1940 monograph, "The consistency of the axiom of choice and of the generalized continuum hypothesis with the axioms of set theory". No reason is given for the choice of symbol in either case.

Comment: And $K$ is for *kernel*. It was introduced (or, at least, one of its versions was) in [MR0611394 (82i:03063)](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=611394). Dodd, A.; Jensen, R. *[The core model](https://doi.org/10.1016/0003-4843(81)90011-5)*. Ann. Math. Logic **20** (1981), no. 1, 43–75.

Answer (score 2):

Trivial example, but not to be omitted, the Greek and Latin numerals. E.g.:

[image: Ptolemy's table of chords]

Comment: Yes, and our hexadecimal too. Thanks Pietro for exactly the sort of answer I was hoping for — I added an [image](https://books.google.com/books?id=a9nvvbG-OOIC&pg=PA39) of the [first trigonometric table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemy%27s_table_of_chords#The_numeral_system_and_the_appearance_of_the_untranslated_table) to illustrate. Do we know how they were *verbalizing* the numbers?

Comment: If you mean pronouncing the digit's symbols as letters, I do not have any knowledge about it. I guess a trace of it, if any, could be found in dramatic literature, which is one important source of information about the spelling of classic languages. After all it could be, like anglophones sometimes do when spelling $0$ as "oh" instead of "zero". It is also true that digits and numeric codes enter in our life in a very massive way, that did not exist in ancient times, when on the contrary written names were more used than symbols even in formulas.

Comment: It would be funny to know of Roman boys greeting each other with "da mihi v"

Answer (score 0):

Given that there is not much difference between a *letter* and a *symbol* (especially in view of the two most upvoted answers), I propose:

• The letter "+" is used for the mathematical object commonly called *addition*.

• The letter "-" is used for the mathematical object commonly called *subtraction*.

• The letter "×" is used for the mathematical object commonly called *multiplication*.

Etc.

Comment: Besides, the symbol "+" comes from a Latin *et*, after the contraction of "e", so it's indeed the single letter "t".

Comment: @PietroMajer So in a sense $+$ is $\&$ then :D